# When TCN is used for prediction（python）, there is a valueerror: high is out of bounds for int32. I can't find out why

Tags: python, u8darts

The database is darts and the code is GitHub- https://unit8co.github.io/darts/examples/06-TCN-examples.html
Every example here is used on pychar with the following errors
My environment is created by CONDA, and the virtual environment is Python 3.8

**Error message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/pycharm/testtcn/energy.py", line 33, in <module>
    model_en = TCNModel(
  File "D:\anconda\envs\env_name\lib\site-packages\darts\utils\torch.py", line 64, in decorator
    manual_seed(self._random_instance.randint(0, high=MAX_TORCH_SEED_VALUE))
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 745, in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.randint
  File "_bounded_integers.pyx", line 1343, in numpy.random._bounded_integers._rand_int32
ValueError: high is out of bounds for int32
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to the file `...\site-packages\darts\utils\torch.py` in your system
2. Find the line `MAX_TORCH_SEED_VALUE = (1 << 63) - 1` which should be around line 17
3. Change it to `MAX_TORCH_SEED_VALUE = (1 << 31) - 1` so that it fits into 32 bit int.

After saving this change, code should run fine.

(credit: https://github.com/unit8co/darts/issues/235#issue-737158114)

Comment: Oh, bless you! That's very kind of you.